# Matlab, How to compare a matrix with kmeans centroids and get the indexes?

Tags: matlab, compare, k-means

Let's say i have this matrix:

```
A =

    0.9619    0.1154    0.6569
    0.1416    0.5193    0.6535
    0.3161    0.3956    0.6096
```

When i calculate the kmeans using matlab i get this:

```
>> [idx,C] = kmeans(A,3)

idx =

     1
     2
     3


C =

    0.9619    0.1154    0.6569
    0.1416    0.5193    0.6535
    0.3161    0.3956    0.6096
```

What i want to do is bring another Matrix B and compare it with C and get its indexes?

Comment: Just a little question: Do you understand Kmeans? Because computing 3 centroids to a 3 point array using kmeans makes absolutely no sense (you may notice the centroids ARE the points, of course)

Comment: @Ander Biguri Yes, this is just for the purpose of simplifying the question, because in reality i have like 20 images, i calculate their feature vectors and reshape them into 9*9 matrices, then i put all the matrices into one big matrix, and i apply the kmeans with 9 clusters, and get the indexes for each image. but i don't know how to bring one image of those 20 and compare it with the produced centroids to get its indexes.

Comment: I dont know, I guess euclidean distance? Check around feature matching algorithms, there are plenty of optios